# How to take values generated from a MATLAB program and display them in a Simulink block?

Tags: matlab, arduino, simulink, encoder

I have a working MATLAB program hooked up to an Arduino and rotary sensor that displays the current angle. I would like to display this angle on a Simulink model, so I can control a motor based off the current angle. Is there any way to do this without creating an angle sensor in Simulink and just using my MATLAB code that already works?

Comment: What about "display" block? Add a "mux" before that and display the variables, as much as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear and it depends if you are trying to do it **before** simulation or **during** simulation.

If you want to do it **before** the simulation, just create a constant block with a variable name that is taken from the workspace, and let your function to set that variable in the workspace.

If you want to do it **during** simulation, it is a little more difficult but still possible. Lets create a sample a MVCE. The simulink model `mask.slx` contains a constant the is set to 0, and this constant value is displayed in the display block on the right. The simulation time is set to `inf`, so when you play it, you must stop it manually.

[image]

It is possible to checge the value of the constant **while the simulation is running** using this simple Matlab call:

```
set_param('mask/Value_to_set', 'Value', '10')
```

you should also consider that the constanta must be a Tunable gain (it is by default).

[image]

(as you can see the simulation is running).

There are some additional (and surely better) solution you can use:

1. Include your Matlab function in a MATLAB User Defined Function block, and call it at each simulation iteration. If you have compilation issue you shall follow the `coder.extrinsic` way ([here an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42054642/calling-fmincon-from-simulink/50585982#50585982) for `fmincon`)
2. Use the Simulink Support Package for Arduino Uno Hardware Add-on that is available in the Add on store.